# How to prove the monotonicity of nth root of n (natural numbers)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am currently practicing series and I have come across this problem many times.

I know how to prove that $$\large n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ is bounded by $1$ and by $2$.

What I don't know is how to prove its monotonicity for natural numbers without using derivatives and expansions.

Can anyone help?

Comment: But it isn't monotone.

Comment: @Gae.S. How so?

Comment: Because $\sqrt[4]4=\sqrt2< \sqrt[3]3$.

Comment: @Gae.S. That's a terribly incomplete and one-sided answer. More so because I never said over all natural numbers.

Comment: "What I don't know is how to prove its monotonicity for natural numbers without using derivatives and expansions."

Comment: @Gae.S. Read it out loud one more time. If you get stuck I'll be around to re-word it into more simple terms.

Comment: Monotonicity is inherently a global property: if you don't want it globally, you have to state it, rather than suggesting that others cannot read your precious pieces of wisdom.